# Squeak: Testing and using streams

Tags: unit-testing, stream, smalltalk, squeak

I have an object with a message that gets a stream and print into it.
My problem is testing that I am printing the right string.
I could do it with output redirection and a testing script, but I would rather do it using the assert of the TestCase class, if that is possible.
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Some sample code would help...

Comment: I have a calss A, and in it a message called (printOn:) that is printing a string describing the A object into a given stream.

Comment: You can create a stream using `WriteStream on: String new` and send `contents` to it for retriving its contents.

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin: Might be worth creating an answer from your comment so Mugen can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a stream that writes to an in-memory string with `WriteStream on: String new`.

Send `contents` to that stream for retrieving the string contents.

That should help you test your code.